# build with clang causes "'type_traits' file not found"

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I try to build [this](https://github.com/Davidbrcz/header-expander) with clang and CMake. But when I build, I get an error :

> In file included from C:\Users\Yoann\Downloads\header-expander-master\src\BaseVisitor.cpp:1:
>   In file included from C:\Users\Yoann\Downloads\header-expander-master\src\BaseVisitor.h:4:
>   In file included from C:\LLVM\bin..\lib\clang\3.6.2../../../include\clang/AST/AST.h:18:
>   In file included from C:\LLVM\bin..\lib\clang\3.6.2../../../include\clang/AST/ASTContext.h:18:
>   In file included from C:\LLVM\bin..\lib\clang\3.6.2../../../include\clang/AST/ASTTypeTraits.h:20:
>   In file included from C:\LLVM\bin..\lib\clang\3.6.2../../../include\clang/AST/Decl.h:17:
>   In file included from C:\LLVM\bin..\lib\clang\3.6.2../../../include\clang/AST/APValue.h:17:
>   In file included from C:\LLVM\bin..\lib\clang\3.6.2../../../include\clang/Basic/LLVM.h:22:
>   In file included from C:\LLVM\bin..\lib\clang\3.6.2../../../include\llvm/Support/Casting.h:19:
>   C:\LLVM\bin..\lib\clang\3.6.2../../../include\llvm/Support/type_traits.h:17:10: fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found

`type_traits` is a `stdlib++` file(I get `mingw` with `stdlib++`). How I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I got a similar problem once when cross-compiling PCRE with mingw... I think I basically ended up reconfiguring the build so that it didn't require this file. Would like to know if there's a better way.